# How do I get Rails 3.1 to not add X-CSRF-Token to my JSONP requests that go to a third party?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jsonp

I'm using a third-party JavaScript client library that uses jQuery to send JSONP requests. The requests are getting stamped with X-CSRF-Token, but Google Chrome is blocking them, saying

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load [...]. Request header field X-CSRF-Token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`

How do I get Rails 3.1 to not add X-CSRF-Token to my requests that go to the third party?

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem. This bug is actually fixed in the current development version of jquery-rails.

What's happening there is due to the [CSRFProtect function](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/6f15a60fad3f0f5aa1acece343e20e0837a39a1d/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js#L76) of the rails helpers, that adds that header to every ajax request, but it doesn't make sense for cross domain. Since jQuery 1.5, you're able to add a `crossDomain` option to the ajax config to force requests to be considered cross-domain, and the current version of jquery-rails fixes that [here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/6f15a60fad3f0f5aa1acece343e20e0837a39a1d/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js#L258).

Now, there are two ways to set the crossDomain option:

- If you're building a form or a link, you can add, respectively, `:html => {'data-cross-domain' => true}` or `'data-cross-domain' => true` (cf. [the source](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/6f15a60fad3f0f5aa1acece343e20e0837a39a1d/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js#L101) )
- If you're using the raw `$.ajax` function, then just remember to add `crossDomain: true` to the options.

**TL;DR** upgrade to the latest version (i.e. the current dev version in github) of jquery_rails and remember the crossDomain option.